# JSession::getFormToken() vs JUtility::getToken()

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.2

Guyz, I have seen both of these in practical use quiet a lot...

```
JSession::getFormToken() vs JUtility::getToken()
```

Now I wish to know if they are the same(then why named differently), do they belong to different Joomla! versions, and if one is prefered which should I go with?

Note: I have searched enough and I must say both seem to be used equally, in official docs, tutorials, stackoverflow answers, etc..

**UPDATE:-** As of 7-FEB-2014 the official pages for both   [**JSession::getFormToken()**](http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JSession::getFormToken) and [**JUtility::getToken()**](http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JUtility::getToken)    are showing this warning..

[image: Joomla Deprecated Notice]

While [**this**](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms) page which is clearly intended for 2.5-3.xx states the use of

```
JSession::getFormToken()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say only one difference with these two.

It is based on Joomla api version. `JUtility::getToken()` is available from Joomla 1.5 and 
`JSession::getFormToken`  available from Joomla 1.6.

In fact both are doing same task like [here](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJUtility%3a%3agetToken) and [this](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJSession%3a%3agetFormToken).
 So may be in future `JUtility::getToken()` may be depreciated or removed from latest versions like what Joomla did for `DS` constant Its available from `J1.5` to `J2.5` but on `J3.x`  Its removed and they use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

Comment: But atm, both are displaying the depricated notice on both the links you posted which is as follows ... "This Namespace has been archived - Please Do Not Edit or Create Pages in this namespace. Pages contain information for a Joomla! version which is no longer supported. It exists only as a historical reference, will not be improved and its content may be incomplete."

Comment: both of the are showing such warning but in latest version of Joomla is using Jession:: method and Jutility is not even used in Joomla3.x

Answer (score 2):

According to me, the documentation pages of Joomla are updated. That's why you get those messages 'The Namespace has been archived'. Use http://api.joomla.org to find the new documentation.

JUtility::getToken() is deprecated. See: http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JUtility.html#method_getToken. It tells you to use JSession::getFormToken().

Comment: did you mean ...documentation pages of Joomla are 'outdated' ?

Comment: @wardha-Web I don't know all the details, but the links you referred to for JSession::getFormToken() and JUtility::getToken() are for Joomla 1.7 and so 'outdated'. What I meant with 'updated' is that the documentation for the api of Joomla 2.5 has been put under api.joomla.org, instead of docs.joomla.org, and with a new layout.